# Why does periodically pressing the enter key substantially speed up my code?

Tags: python, python-idle

I inadvertently ran across a phenomenon that has me a bit perplexed. I was using IDLE for some quick testing, and I had some very simple code like this (which I have simplified for the purpose of illustration):

```
from time import clock  # I am presently using windows

def test_speedup():
    c = clock()
    for i in range(1000):
        print i,
    print '=>', clock() - c
```

Now I ran this code like so (several times, with the same basic results):

```
# without pressing enter
>>> test_speedup()
0 1 2 3 4 . . . 997 998 999 => 12.8300956124  # the time to run code in seconds

# pressing enter ONLY 3 TIMES while the code ran
>>> test_speedup()
0 1 2 3 4 . . . 997 998 999 => 4.8656890089

# Pressing enter several times while the code ran
>>> test_speedup()
0 1 2 3 4 . . . 997 998 999 => 1.91522580283
```

My first hunch was that perhaps the code ran faster because the output system perhaps did not have to collate as many strings when I pressed enter (beginning anew each time I pressed enter). In fact, the output system always seemed to receive a boost in speed immediately after I pressed enter.

I have also reviewed the [documentation here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print), but I am still a little puzzled why three newline characters would speed things up so substantially.

This question is admittedly somewhat trivial, unless one would like to know how to speed up the output system in IDLE without aborting the script. Still, I would like to understand what is happening with the output system here.

(I am using Python 2.7.x.)

Comment: As a side note, don't try to time things with `time.clock()`; use `timeit`. For coarsely-grained tests like this, where there's an obvious order-of-magnitude difference, it's not a big deal, but it's worth getting into the habit of doing things right.

Comment: @abarnert Point taken. Thanks for the helpful advice.

Comment: When I run this on a Mac, I can actually see it slow down as the line gets longer. It gradually gets slower, and there are also two points (around 500 and 920) where it suddenly gets a whole lot slower. Which implies that it is the long-lines issue, not the blocking-on-input issue…

Comment: The underling issue is that tcl/tk Text widgets are optimized for screen-sized lines and slows down for 'long' lines.  But it will handle at least 500,000 short lines (the most I tested).  The Windows console does not choke on long lines but will only keep a fairly small finite number of lines in a ring buffer.  The maximum is 9999 and the default is 300.  When the 301st line is printed, the 1st is deleted, and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the covers, IDLE is simulating a terminal on top of a Tk widget, which I'm pretty sure is ultimately derived from [`Text`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm).

The presence of long lines slows down that widget a little bit. And appending to long lines takes longer than appending to short ones. If you really want to understand why this happens, you need to look at the Tcl code underlying the [`Tk Text`](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html) widget, which `Tkinter.Text` is just a thin wrapper around.

Meanwhile, the Tkinter loop that IDLE runs does some funky things to allow it to accept input without blocking the loop. When it thinks there's nothing else going on, it may sometimes block for a short time until it sees input or a Tk event, and all of those short blocks may add up; pressing Enter may just cancel a few of them.

I'm not actually sure which of these two is more relevant here. You'd have to test it with a program that just spams long lines vs. one that inserts newlines every, say, 10 numbers, and see how much of the performance improvement you get that way.

From a quick test on my Mac, the original program visibly slows down gradually, and also has two quantum jumps in sluggishness around 500 and 920. So, it makes sense that hitting enter every 333 or so would speed things up a lot—you likely avoid both of those quantum slowdowns. If I change it to just remove the comma, the problem goes away.

Printing a newline for every number could of course cause a *different* slowdown, because that makes the terminal long enough to need to scroll, increases the scrollback buffer, etc. I didn't see that cost in IDLE, but run the same thing on the Windows command line, and you'll see problems with too many newlines just as bad as the problems with too few in IDLE. The best tradeoff should probably come from "square"-ish data, or data that's as close to 80 columns as possible without going over.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll check out Tkinter.Text for further explanation. I'll accept this answer (and upvote it, if I can, although I don't seem to have the rep yet) in just a little bit (just to make sure no other insights arise). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has something to do with the IDE that you are using to execute your code.

I have run your code (with syntax alterations for 3.3) and got the same time to execute both times:

999
=> 8.09542283367021

**edit**: This was performed in stock IDLE with Python 3.3. I spammed the enter key with multiple experiments and witnessed no time difference between string output on the control v. the experiment.

On a hunch, I decided to remove a print function and condense it into one line.:

```
print(i, "=>", clock()-c)
```

this produced 999 => 7.141783124325343

On this basis, I believe that the time differential you are seeing is due to the IDE sucking up more threads to process your code which results in faster times. Clearly, the time at the end is the total amount of time to compute and print your for loop.

To confirm my suspicion, I decided to put everything into a list of tuples and then print that list.

```
def new_speed_test():
    speed_list = []
    c = clock()
    for i in range(1000):
        speed_list.append((i, clock()-c))
    print(speed_list[-1])
```

which output: (999, 0.0005668934240929957)

To conclude: My experiment confirms it is how *your IDE* handles output and CPU consumption.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP already knows that. The question is about IDLE's output system, and even acknowledges that "This question is admittedly somewhat trivial, unless one would like to know how to speed up the output system in IDLE without aborting the script."

Comment: I thought that I read the question and understood it properly before answering; however, after re-reading it I see what you mean. Arguably, the only person whose time I've wasted is my own so no real damage done (as my answer isn't misleading... at the worst it's simply a waste of 30 seconds to read).

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it serves as a correct and at least marginally useful commentary. After all, the OP was only _guessing_ that it's IDLE's output system that's to blame, and your answer helps to confirm that. That's why I just added a comment, rather than downvoting or flagging or something.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my original post that even with spamming the enter key I did not get a change in the output time, which is the whole reason I put the post here to begin with (oops). It isolates the incident to whatever IDE the Questioner was using as IDLE standard with Python 3.3 does not have the observed behavior.

Comment: I see the same behavior on two different Macs using IDLE, with python.org 3.3 with Apple Tcl/Tk, python.org 3.3 with ActiveState Tcl/Tk, and custom-built 3.4 with included Tcl/Tk. (The `clock` output is of course useless on non-Windows, but the speed difference is readily visible.)

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference between the two machines? At this point I'm speculating because I don't have any knowledge of the TCL/TK but I would assume that a difference between the two macs (all software being identical) comes down to hardware discrepancies. Is this incorrect? If so, how/why? I find this interesting!

Comment: I was guessing you weren't on a Mac… If you are, then I'd still look at other software issues before looking at hardware. I'm using a pretty fast machine, so it doesn't seem likely that yours is so much faster that it manages to completely hide the problem.

Comment: Actually, re-reading your answer, if you're judging based on the output of `time.clock`, that's really not very useful on anything but Windows, for the reasons explained in the docs. As I said in my previous comment, the output speed dramatically and visibly slows down if you don't hit Enter, and doesn't slow down if you do, and that's what I was judging based on. If you really want to quantify it, use `clock_gettime`—or, better, the `timeit` module.